# junit 4.10: how to get the name of the tests class while running tests

Tags: java, testing, junit

I'd like to know how to get the class name that is running a given tests. To get the name of a test I use the @Rule TestName.

But if I want the test class, how do I get it?

Comment: Like in the method body of the test case?  `this.getClass().getName()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use

```
this.getClass().getName()
```

or

```
this.getClass().getSimpleName()
```

Depending if you want the full name with package or just the simple class name.

Comment: @mszlbach: What if we want to get a class name for another class that executes the test in parallel mode.